# Linq statement to conditionally include or exclude then count results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm having trouble with a linq statement to provide data in the way I need for my view.

This is the data I have:

```
AgentName   questions
Alison          1
Alison          1
Alison          0
Jack            0
Jack            99
Jack            1
```

I need to be able to have a dataset that counts 1 and 0, but ignores 99.  So in the above example, Alison had 2 questions (1) correct, and 1 question (0) wrong.  Jack had 1 question correct (1), and one wrong (0), and one doesn't count (99).  The resulting data would be:

```
AgentName   questions Correct    Question Wrong
Alison          2                  1
Jack            1                  1
```

What I've tried is:

```
   var results = qas.GroupBy(x => x.AgentName)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AnalystId = x.Key,
        Analyst = x.FirstOrDefault().Analyst.AgentName,
        Correct= x.Count().Where(x => x.questions ==1),
        Wrong= x.Count().Where(x => x.questions ==0)
    })
```

...but it fails on:

```
Correct= x.Count().Where(x => x.questions ==1),
Wrong= x.Count().Where(x => x.questions ==0)
```

I'd appreciate any guidance,

Thanks, Mark

Comment: The answers already tell you what's wrong, I just want to add: In such cases you should ask yourself what `x` represents in your Linq-Query. If you're clear about that, most problems solve themselves ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this

```
 var results = qas.GroupBy(x => x.AgentName)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AnalystId = x.Key,
        Analyst = x.FirstOrDefault().Analyst.AgentName,
        Correct= x.Where(x => x.questions ==1).Count(),
        Wrong= x.Where(x => x.questions ==0).Count()
    })
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll mark as the answer as soon as SO allows (10 mins or so) - thanks to Felipe and Sharooz also.

Answer (score 5):

The `Count` method return a integer value, so, you cannot cann the `Where` extension method from an integer. Try using directly the `Count` method with the overload where you can pass a condition to perform it, for sample:

```
   var results = qas.GroupBy(x => x.AgentName)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AnalystId = x.Key,
        Analyst = x.FirstOrDefault().Analyst.AgentName,
        Correct= x.Count(k => k.questions == 1),
        Wrong= x.Count(k => k.questions == 0)
    });
```

And also rename the variable of your expression in `Count` method to avoid confusing the code.

Comment: Definite +1 for renaming the variable to avoid confusion for the code and the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

USe :

```
 var results = qas.GroupBy(x => x.AgentName)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AnalystId = x.Key,
        Analyst = x.FirstOrDefault().Analyst.AgentName,
        Correct= x.Where(x => x.questions ==1).Count(),
        Wrong= x.Where(x => x.questions ==0).Count()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is not SQL. You cannot use `Count().Where()`.

Do it the other way around: `Where().Count()`, or just use `Count()` with the condition between the parentheses (this is equivalent to first calling `Where` and then doing a `Count`).

Answer (score 1):

Your count is misplaced here. It should be after the where clause.

```
Correct= x.Count().Where(x => x.questions ==1),
```

should be

```
Correct= x.Where(x => x.questions ==1).Count(),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var results = qas.GroupBy(x => x.AgentName)
.Select(x => new
{
    AnalystId = x.Key,
    Analyst = x.FirstOrDefault().Analyst.AgentName,
    Correct= x.Where(x => x.questions ==1).Count(),
    Wrong= x.Where(x => x.questions ==0).Count()
})
```

the result of x.Count() is integer and it does'n have 'questions' Property